# Why is a package defined within the Pycharm Sources not found?

Tags: pycharm

As can be seen from the screenshot the `framework` directory is defined as a `Sources Root` .

[image]

However the `ddex` package is not recognized even though an `__init__.py` is present.

[image]

Note: the command line `pytest` works fine and also *other* `Pycharm` projects [on the same repo] do not have an issue.  I'm not sure why *this* project is behaving in this manner.